# How to change receive location of blutooth transfer files in android

Tags: android

I've done file transfer via bluetooth between two devices in android well.It received into bluetooth received folder by default.Is it possible to change the receive location of files?
For ex. i've my own application installed on both devices(D1 & D2). From my app on D1,ive send a file to D2.Is it possible to receive tht file directly  into my own app on D2 to open?
if so how could i do tht?

My code:

```
sendDirectly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (devices.size() > 0) {
                for ( BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                    deviceBTAddress=device.getAddress();
                }

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                // values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(new
                // File(uri.getPath())).toString());
                values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, uri.toString());
                values.put(BluetoothShare.MIMETYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, deviceBTAddress);
                values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, 
                           BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
                Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
                final Uri contentUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                                       .insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html

Take a look at this, i would say this would be a better option of programmatically sending a file over Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler than the way you are setting it up - all you need to do is go into your computer's Control Panel and navigate to your Bluetooth settings and click on "Change Bluetooth Settings." From there, you can quickly determine where you wish to have the incoming file transfers saved, and you can even delegate PIM settings to send things such as Business Cards & Calendar Items to send via Bluetooth directly into your Outlook Thunderbird or whichever email client you use. Same concept goes for mobile devices. Just go into the Bluetooth Settings and change the defaults to your custom locations for where you want to have incoming BT transfers saved.